# Matching sections of text

Tags: bash

I want to do pattern matching to display section of texts within a file matching the following structure.

```
## DN [Pattern-Matching] glob,regex
## Some text
## More text
## DN [Pattern-Matching] ends here
```

The syntax in

```
## DN [TITLE] KEYWORD[,KEYWORD..]
## Some text
## More text
## DN [TITLE] ends here
```

Where TITLE in any title, with keywords (multiple keywords separated by comma).

To display the section, the user supplies the `TITLE` or `KEYWORD`.

Have started with the following label

```
  lab="## DN [Something]"
```

The pattern to match the above I have done with.

```
  if [[ "$lab" =~ ^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]DN[[:space:]]\[.*\]$ ]]; then
```

Now I have to match the additional keywords parts.

For the last part I want to match `keyword,keyword`

Which I have started doing with `([^,]+)`.  My confusion is matching
the remaining possibilities of zero or more `,keyword` after that.

Comment: Remove the trailing `$` from the RE. Do you now get a match? If so perhaps the input file has come from a Windows system with CR/LF line endings?

Answer (score 0):

Use awk or perl for text processing, not bash.

e.g. with awk:

```
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*##[[:blank:]]+DN[[:blank:]]+\[TITLE\]/ {
       if (p) print;
       p = ! p
     };
     p' input.txt 
## DN [TITLE] KEYWORD[,KEYWORD..]
## Some text
## More text
## DN [TITLE] ends here
```

BTW, in case you're not familiar with awk, the final `p` after the semi-colon in the awk script tests if `p` is true and prints the current line if it is - it's shorthand equivalent to `{if (p) print}`.  In short: awk scripts consist of a series of "PATTERN ACTION" rules, and either PATTERN or ACTION can be omitted. A PATTERN is anything that evaluates as true or false. If the PATTERN is omitted, the default is to evaluate as true (i.e the ACTION will always be executed).  An ACTION is awk code to be executed. If the ACTION is omitted, the default is `print`.

or with perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'if (/^\h*##\h+DN\h+\[TITLE\]/) {
              print if $p;
              $p = ! $p
            };
            print if $p' input.txt 
## DN [TITLE] KEYWORD[,KEYWORD..]
## Some text
## More text
## DN [TITLE] ends here
```

Both scripts operate identically - they're direct translations of each other.

In both scripts, variable `p` (`$p` for perl) is being used as a toggle, to switch printing on and off whenever the pattern is seen.

Both scripts requires a little code-duplication. The code block that toggles `p` (or `$p`) has to check if `p` is true and print if it is **before** toggling `p`.  Otherwise the final line of the block you want wouldn't be printed because `p` has been toggled off just before the "print if p is true" test is executed.

NOTE: `[[:blank:]]` means space or tab.  perl's `\h` means **any** horizontal whitespace (including, depending on locale, some unicode whitespace characters).  In practice, both will work the same for ASCII text.

---

If you need to test for two conditions, then use two variables - say `p1` and `p2` (`$p1` and `$p2` for perl).  Test for them individually, and only print if both are true: e.g. `p1 && p2` in awk, `print if ($p1 && $p2)` in perl.

Shell variables can be passed from shell to awk or perl either via the command line, or via environment variables (`export` a variable in bash and it will be available in the environment of all child processes).